# Cause of performance difference in various iterators

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, iterator, difference

While playing with the new array functions of **JavaScript**, i saw some major differences in performance in the following code: **jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jKUm5/**

**Slowest `for var i in array` (67.2ms):**

```
for (var a=0;a<amount;a++) {
    for (var b in arr) {
        arr[b]++;
    }
}
```

**JS 5.1 `array.forEach` (2.1ms):**

```
for (var c=0;c<amount;c++) {
    arr.forEach(function(e,i,a) {
        arr[i]++;
    });
}
```

**Fastest (default)`for var i=0;i<array.length;i++` (1.1ms):**

```
for (var d=0;d<amount;d++) {
    for (var e=0;e<arr.length;e++) {
        arr[e]++;
    }
}
```

I thought it was a good practice to use `for var i in array` instead of the default, but it seems that the default is the most fast!

My main questions are:

- What is the reason behind the bad performance of `for var i in array`?
- What is the difference between the default iterators and the new one (what is the necessity of having ANOTHER iterator method)?

Comment: for-in loops should not be used on arrays, but objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `for-in` loop iterates all properties on an object, not just array values.  As such, it has to retrieve those property values from the object rather than just manufacture an array index like the other two methods are doing.  Besides being the wrong way to iterate arrays, it does not surprise me that it is slower.  But regardless of speed, it's the wrong way to iterate arrays.  If anyone adds an iterable method or property to the `Array` prototype, that property will show up in your `for-in` array iteration.

`.forEach()` is there for convenience and sometimes the closure created by the callback is convenient (especially when you want to access the array index in an async callback).  It is likely slower because it involves a function call with arguments for each iteration vs. your third method which has no extra function call on each iteration.

FYI, the `.forEach()` method is the slowest of the three in Firefox so this varies by browser too.